# Data format issue. Export GridView to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

There was a string `(1008901023816550000000)` in the GridView somehow was saved as a scientific number `(1.0089E+21)` in Excel when I exported the GridView to Excel.

I am using .Net 4.0.

Here is what I tried, but they didn't solve the problem:

1. Added `DataFormatString="{0:g}"` to the `BoundColumn` tag.
2. Set the `style` after the `RenderControl` was called.

```
    string style = @"<style> .text { mso-number-format:\@; } </script> ";
```

Can anyone shed some light on this problem?

Comment: Stick a single quote (`'`) before the value to force Excel to treat it as a string and not a number? Don't know if that works programmaticlaly, but it does for manual entry directly into Excel.

Comment: @Marc B: Thanks. I just tried, but '1008901023816550000000 with the single quote will be stored as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you are using a CSV file to perform the export:

This is a quirk of Excel that's hard to shake. The only idea I know of is to try using a format like this inside the CSV file:

```
="1008901023816550000000"
```

This will force it to be a formula that returns the desired text.

Comment: @sza: Yep, you're stuck with an equal sign and the double quotes. Sorry. But given what Excel will and won't do, this might be the only possible way. On the upside, as far as the spreadsheet calculations and formatting is concerned, it's a bona fide text value and not a number.

Answer (score 3):

Try This, It will work.

```
string style = @"<style> TD { mso-number-format:\@; } </style> ";
```

Comment: sza - I know it is too late but just for update, have you tried the above code? Just Add ONE LINE. you don't have to change your data.