# dataformatstring for converting scientific to number

Tags: c#, boundfield

I am trying to bound a datafield which is a string datatype  (varchar in SQL Server)
and i am exporting into Excel which is leading to an extra space at the end.

Could anyone pleae suggest me to resolve the issue?

I tried to format the string as

```
a.DataFormatString = "{0}&nbsp;"
```

It is displaying as number but adding extra blank space at the end, how to trim the blank space ?

ex: It should display as '**123456789000**', but the ouput in export cell is '**123456789000** '  {extra space at the end}

Comment: (e.Column as GridBoundColumn).DataFormatString = "&nbsp;{0}&nbsp;";-- this thing is adding space infront and back.

Comment: Add code to the question with an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21274058/edit) instead of posting in the comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032409/data-format-issue-export-gridview-to-excel

Answer (score 0):

It's an Excel formatting issue.  To get around it, you need to specify the Excel column format on the HTML table.  This is done by adding `style="mso-number-format:\@;"` to the `<td>` tag. By default `System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid` does not render custom styles, so you need a new control class derived from DataGrid as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    protected override void OnItemDataBound(DataGridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnItemDataBound(e);

        if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Item && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.AlternatingItem) return;

        var dt = DataSource as DataTable;

        if (dt != null)
        {       
            for (int i=0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dt.Columns[i].DataType == typeof(string))
                {
                    e.Item.Cells[i].Style["mso-number-format"] = @"\@";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here is a sample HTML output opened in Excel:

```
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr>
    <td>Field1</td><td>Field2</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td style="mso-number-format:\@;">1321365465465</td><td>123</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td style="mso-number-format:\@;">1321365465465</td><td>123</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

---

### References:

- [Export to EXCEL from Datatable in C#.Net](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/344604/Export-to-EXCEL-from-Datatable-in-Csharp-Net)
- [Basic HTML to Excel Formatting](http://www.niallodoherty.com/post.cfm/basic-html-to-excel-formatting)
- [DataGrid.OnItemDataBound Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.onitemdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: No, I want to convert E to number..ur code will give me E format

Comment: If i do {0}, I can see Expotential number in excel.

Comment: This is an Excel formatting issue.  How are you exporting the data to Excel?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/344604/Export-to-EXCEL-from-Datatable-in-Csharp-Net  - In this way i am exporting to excel. But i have issue with specific column